# PHP upload fail (empty $_FILES)

Tags: php, arrays, upload

I have a common problem in PHP : My $_FILES array is empty when files are too big.

php.ini :

```
max_execution_time = 300000
max_input_time = 600000000
memory_limit = 5100MB
post_max_size = 5000MB
upload_max_filesize = 5000MB
```

The file :

```
Trouve.tar : 910Mo
```

Configuration values are huge but I want to be sure that the script have the time and the memory to do the upload.

So, the authorized size is bigger than the file size, but I have the same error than other people (like [problem with uploading the images with php file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181352/problem-with-uploading-the-images-with-php-file-upload) for exemple)

Have I missed some configuration setting ?

Comment: Seriously, is that 910 megabytes? I didn't look it up, but PHP likely has some builtin hard limits.

Comment: Just to clarify, it works with small files?

Comment: @Naatan Yes it works without any problems.

Comment: Single file? Must it be a form request? Else capturing a PUT request might make sense.

Comment: @mario Yes it is a single file from a form request. I didn't know PUT request, I'll try this.

Comment: Using firebug or equivalent to track the http request, does it upload the full 910mb? Have you checked the response headers for any clues as to why its faling?

Comment: Caveat: PUT doesn't work via forms. Major browsers support it via AJAX at best. So that's why I put that use case question forward. It's a probable option if you do server to server uploads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of MB use M

```
memory_limit = 5100M

post_max_size = 5000M

upload_max_filesize = 5000M
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is your **post_max_size** is the same size as **upload_max_filesize** which will cause the $_FILES array (and $_POST) to be empty. If you up the limit on the post_max_size, the $_FILES array will no longer be empty.

EDIT: Not sure why the negative vote. While it may not apply exactly in this case, it is worth mentioning. This is exactly what php.net says: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size.

> If the size of post data is greater
>   than post_max_size,  the $_POST and
>   $_FILES  superglobals  are empty.

Comment: Negative vote was not mine. Sorry. I'll try what you said when I will have time. For the moment I gave up. Thank you.

Comment: @ChuckBurgess Its a true fact :)

Answer (score 3):

Check your `upload_limit` in your php.ini settings.

In your html form tag, do not forget to put this: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Thank you hlegius but I cant find "upload_limit" in my php.ini and seems to not exists : http://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site:php.net+max_execution_time#sclient=psy&hl=fr&safe=off&q=site:php.net+%22upload_limit%22&aq=&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=92e401c307f5f81f. My form works with small files (until approximatively 300Mo), so yes "enctype="multipart/form-data"" is set.

Answer (score 1):

Check you web server limits in addition to the php.ini configuration.

For example, you'll probably have to increase the [`LimitRequestBody`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) if you're using Apache or the [`client_max_body_size`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size) if you're using nginx.

When an HTTP request is larger that the limit accepted by the web server, it returns an HTTP response with status: 413 Request Entity Too Large.

Comment: LimitRequestBody has been set to 0 (no limit) and the result script is shown (no server error for a "too large file").

Comment: Make sure these settings are OK in the php.ini or the virtual host configuration file: `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size`, `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time`. What's the output when debugging: `var_dump($_FILES)` and `var_dump($_REQUEST)`? You may also try activating `LogLevel debug` in Apache to check any problems the server logs when you upload the file.